# Remove prefix from name python

Tags: python, regex, string, formatting, format

```
names = [
'LIC. SEBASTIÁN LASTIRI',
'ING. AGR. ROBERTO DANIEL RODRÍGUEZ',
'C.P.N. JULIO DOMINGO BURAK',
'INGENIERO HIDRÁULICO VÍCTOR AGUSTÍN PORRINO'
]
```

I have such list with names, i need to remove prefix like ('lic', 'c.p.n' etc) from name (this is just sample there is a lot of prefixes in such format)

output shell be like this :

> 'SEBASTIÁN LASTIRI'

I have tried to :

```
for i in names:
   if '.' in i:
        i.split('.')[1]
```

But it works only when there is one dot in prefix
How to solve this

Comment: Do you want to remove something from 'INGENIERO HIDRÁULICO VÍCTOR AGUSTÍN PORRINO' ? From 'ING. AGR. ROBERTO DANIEL RODRÍGUEZ' ? How do you distinguish a "prefix" from a name ?

Comment: @Jérôme if there is prefix - there should be more then one dot

Comment: Also, 'there should be more than one dot' makes your question false because `LIC. SEBASTIÁN LASTIRI` has exactly one dot and thus not more than one, and hence, does not have a prefix...

Comment: I'm not sure why you used the `regex` tag, but you certainly don't need to use `re`: `result = [n.split(".")[-1].strip() for n in names]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for your issue:

```
import re

names = [
    'LIC. SEBASTIÁN LASTIRI',
    'ING. AGR. ROBERTO DANIEL RODRÍGUEZ',
    'C.P.N. JULIO DOMINGO BURAK',
    'INGENIERO HIDRÁULICO VÍCTOR AGUSTÍN PORRINO'
]

new_names = [re.sub("^\s+", "", i.split(".")[-1]) for i in names]

print new_names # [SEBASTIÁN LASTIRI', ROBERTO DANIEL RODRÍGUEZ', JULIO DOMINGO BURAK', 'INGENIERO HIDRÁULICO VÍCTOR AGUSTÍN PORRINO']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
import re    

names = [
'LIC. SEBASTIAN LASTIRI',
'ING. AGR. ROBERTO DANIEL RODRIGUEZ',
'C.P.N. JULIO DOMINGO BURAK',
'INGENIERO HIDRAULICO VICTOR AGUSTIN PORRINO'
]
for i in names:
    res = re.split(r'\.\s*(?=[^.]+$)', i)
    if len(res) > 1:
        print res[1]
    else:
        print res[0]
```

Output:

```
SEBASTIAN LASTIRI                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
ROBERTO DANIEL RODRIGUEZ                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
JULIO DOMINGO BURAK                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
INGENIERO HIDRAULICO VICTOR AGUSTIN PORRINO
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple filter to only use words without a dot in the end.

```
names = [
    'LIC. SEBASTIÁN LASTIRI',
    'ING. AGR. ROBERTO DANIEL RODRÍGUEZ',
    'C.P.N. JULIO DOMINGO BURAK',
    'INGENIERO HIDRÁULICO VÍCTOR AGUSTÍN PORRINO'
]

names_formated = [' '.join([sub for sub in name.split() if sub[-1] != '.']) for name in names]
```